# FQL : Is it possible to fetch all the emails from my list of Facebook profile ids?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have an FB app that only saves the Facebook profile id of my user and I missed to add the emails.

Now i need to get all the emails of my app users along with their names, one thing i made is to do it one by one but it takes time to finish.

I hope you guys can help me.

UPDATE:

I'm using the normal php authentication and sdk. The only thing i have is the Facebook user id and i'm looking for a way in FQL with the list of Profile ids that will return Email address and fullname.

In mysql it is such like this :

SELECT email FROM user WHERE IN(1234,2355,5553)

Comment: are you doing authentication? using php-sdk? can you put code up(edit your question and add your auth code), if you are doing authentication?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and the docs/the explorer tool state) there's only an "email" and no "friends_email" permission. So you need one access_token with email-permission for each query. So, no. You can't make one query to get email addresses for multiple people. And I don't think Facebook will/should change that soon. Spam etc..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've been testing for a while and they are not allowing email on FQL. The last resort on my problem is to individually make an api call just to fetched the information of my users.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really do batch email gets. However, for each authenticated user you can do `\fql?q=Select email from user where uid=me()` or simply `\me?fields=email`.  I would really suggest you have your legal department read thru https://developers.facebook.com/policy/, paying extra close attention to Policies section IV. 5. and section V enforcement.